# Package babel Error: Unknown language `french' (not 'francais')

Tags: languages, labels

I solve the problem `Unknown option 'francais'` by installing the missing language package:

```
​sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-european
```

Now, encounter the problem **`Unknown language 'french'`**, the detailed error info is as follows:

```
! Package babel Error: Unknown language `french'. Either you have
(babel)                misspelled its name, it has not been installed,
(babel)                or you requested it in a previous run. Fix its name,
(babel)                install it or just rerun the file, respectively.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `texlive-lang-european` is for a bunch of European languages, among which there's not French; do

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-french
```

See https://packages.debian.org/stable/tex/texlive-lang-french and https://packages.debian.org/stable/tex/texlive-lang-european for details about the packages.

Comment: I don't think so. I am informed `texlive-lang-french is already the newest version.` while running `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-french`.

Comment: @SparkandShine In my test I have no problem. What's your version of TeX Live?

Comment: `TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) `. My setting is: `./preamble/preamble.tex:\usepackage[francais]{babel}`.

Comment: @SparkandShine What about `\usepackage[french]{babel}`? If it works, there's no difference with specifying `francais`. If it doesn't, then there's something wrong with your installation.