# Prefixed bibliography labels in different language with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, babel, moderncv, languages, greek

I use moderncv to compile my cv,  I know that the best solution is `biblatex`, so I followed [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123809/51724) to make it properly work with `moderncv`.

My bibliography has entries in three different languages (english, french and greek), and I want to keep the entry's language in the reference list. I have found [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12224/biblatex-per-entry-language-switching). I want to use different .bib files for my papers with prefix by category and reverse numbering (i.e. first paper with number 1, but put on the bottom).

I have succesfully put them all together, but missed only one thing: the main language of the document is greek, but I need the prefixes to be in latin characters, i.e. D instead of Δ. I tried with `\latintext` and `\foreignlanguage{english}{...}`, but apparently I cannot use anything starting with a `\` as a value for `prefixnumbers`.

MWE:

```
 
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage[francais,english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[LGR,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{theses.bib}
@article{gp01,
    author  = {Georgiou, George and Poulios, John},
    title   = {A very interesting {P}aper},
    year    = {2001},
    journal = {Science},
    volume  = {12},
    number  = {9},
    pages   = {390--451},
    hyphenation = {english}
}
@book{pg13,
    author    = {Poulios, John and Georgiou, George},
    title     = {Une livre très importante},
    year      = {2013},
    publisher = {Springer},
    address   = {Paris},
    hyphenation = {francais}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{journals.bib}
@CONFERENCE{CP15,
    author      = {Makridis, Andreas and Poulios, John},
    title       = {Assembly 2015 (Poster)},
    booktitle   = {Astronomical Conference},
    address     = {Athens, Greece},
    date        = {28 June -- 7 July,},
    year        = {2015},
    pages       = {54},
    hyphenation = {english}
}
@ARTICLE{CAgr,
    author      = {Πούλιος, Ιωάννης and Μακρίδης, Ανδρέας},
    title       = {Ελληνικό συνέδριο},
    journal     = {Χρονικά},
    year        = {2014},
    volume      = {54},
    pages       = {043018},
    hyphenation = {greek}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[sorting=ydnt,%      Sort by year (descending), name, title
            style=numeric,%
            firstinits=true,%   Initials on first names
            defernumbers=true,% Required to use 'prefixnumbers' option in \printbibliography
            maxnames=99,%       Show all authors            
            autolang=other%
           ]{biblatex}

% Reverse numbering
% SRC: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37850/51724
\AtDataInput{%
  \csnumgdef{entrycount:\strfield{prefixnumber}}{%
    \csuse{entrycount:\strfield{prefixnumber}}+1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}    
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\strfield{prefixnumber}}+1-#1\relax}

% biblatex for moderncv
% SRC: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123809/51724
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{% label format from numeric.bbx
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}% layout parameters from moderncvstyleclassic.sty
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{\hintscolumnwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \leftmargin\labelwidth%
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}%
      \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

% Make one author bold
% SRC: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211821/51724
\newcommand{\makeauthorbold}[1]{%
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{liststop}}{1}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal{##1}{#1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal{##1}{#1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}}
    {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal{##1}{#1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal{##1}{#1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}%
    }%
}%
}

\addbibresource[label=T]{theses.bib}
\addbibresource[label=J]{journals.bib}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\firstname{Εγώ}
\familyname{Επώνυμο}
\title{Βιογραφικό Σημείωμα}
\address{Εδώ}
\email{me@gmail.com}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\emailsymbol{\latintext}{}{}  % email address written in latin characters
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\makeauthorbold{Poulios}
\begin{refsection}[J]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={Δημοσιεύσεις},prefixnumbers={J}]
\end{refsection}
\begin{refsection}[T]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={Διατριβές},prefixnumbers={D}]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> ... I tried with `\latintext` and `\foreignlanguage{english}{...}`, but
>   apparently I cannot use anything starting with a `\` as a value for
>   `prefixnumbers`.

The trick for that is to enclose the `\printfield{prefixnumber}` with `\foreignlanguage`:

```
\foreignlanguage{english}{\printfield{prefixnumber}}
```

Complete code (I changed `francais` to `french` to get rid of an error message; I do not speak french, so my system is not configured for that, but `french` was okay. I added `\jobname` to the bib files and moved the bib files to be at the beginning of the MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-theses.bib}
@article{gp01,
    author  = {Georgiou, George and Poulios, John},
    title   = {A very interesting {P}aper},
    year    = {2001},
    journal = {Science},
    volume  = {12},
    number  = {9},
    pages   = {390--451},
    language    = {english},
    hyphenation = {english},
}
@book{pg13,
    author    = {Poulios, John and Georgiou, George},
    title     = {Une livre très importante},
    year      = {2013},
    publisher = {Springer},
    address   = {Paris},
    language    = {french},
    hyphenation = {french},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-journals.bib}
@CONFERENCE{CP15,
    author      = {Makridis, Andreas and Poulios, John},
    title       = {Assembly 2015 (Poster)},
    booktitle   = {Astronomical Conference},
    address     = {Athens, Greece},
    date        = {28 June -- 7 July,},
    year        = {2015},
    pages       = {54},
    language    = {english},
    hyphenation = {english},
}
@ARTICLE{CAgr,
    author      = {Πούλιος, Ιωάννης and Μακρίδης, Ανδρέας},
    title       = {Ελληνικό συνέδριο},
    journal     = {Χρονικά},
    year        = {2014},
    volume      = {54},
    pages       = {043018},
    language    = {greek},
    hyphenation = {greek},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage[%
% francais,
  french,
  english,
  greek
]{babel}

\usepackage[LGR,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,%     use biber to create bibliography ...
  sorting=ydnt,%      Sort by year (descending), name, title
  style=numeric,%
  firstinits=true,%   Initials on first names
  defernumbers=true,% Required to use 'prefixnumbers' option in \printbibliography
  maxnames=99,%       Show all authors            
  autolang=other%
]{biblatex}

% Reverse numbering
% SRC: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37850/51724
\AtDataInput{%
  \csnumgdef{entrycount:\strfield{prefixnumber}}{%
    \csuse{entrycount:\strfield{prefixnumber}}+1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}    
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\strfield{prefixnumber}}+1-#1\relax}

% biblatex for moderncv
% SRC: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123809/51724
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{% label format from numeric.bbx
        \foreignlanguage{english}{\printfield{prefixnumber}}% <========================
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}% layout parameters from moderncvstyleclassic.sty
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{\hintscolumnwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \leftmargin\labelwidth%
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}%
      \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

% Make one author bold
% SRC: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211821/51724
\newcommand{\makeauthorbold}[1]{%
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{liststop}}{1}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal{##1}{#1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal{##1}{#1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}}
    {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal{##1}{#1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal{##1}{#1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}%
    }%
}%
}

\addbibresource[label=T]{\jobname-theses.bib}
\addbibresource[label=J]{\jobname-journals.bib}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\firstname{Εγώ}
\familyname{Επώνυμο}
\title{Βιογραφικό Σημείωμα}
\address{Εδώ}
\email{me@gmail.com}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\emailsymbol{\latintext}{}{}  % email address written in latin characters
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\makeauthorbold{Poulios}
\begin{refsection}[J]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={Δημοσιεύσεις},prefixnumbers={J}]
\end{refsection}
\begin{refsection}[T]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={Διατριβές},prefixnumbers={D}]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

BTW: `\latintext` is depreciated ...

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your quick answer! As for the `francais` option, it seems to be unknown to some versions, and `french` to some other, eg. [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139700/package-babel-error-unknown-option-francais) or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254119/package-babel-error-unknown-language-french-not-francais)
Also thank you for noticing `\latintext`, but I tied anything I could imagine.