# Package babel Error: Unknown language `french' still exists after installing texlive-lang-french

Tags: packages, texmaker, languages

I use a latex template on sharelatex and it works fine. However, I encounter the following issue when building it on my laptop (Ubuntu + Texmarker),

```
! Package babel Error: Unknown language `french'. Either you have
(babel) misspelled its name, it has not been installed,
```

This issue probably is caused by the template containing some french words. So I add the package `babel`,

```
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
```

Refer to [Package babel Error: Unknown option francais'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139700/package-babel-error-unknown-option-francais) and [Package babel Error: Unknown language 'french' (not 'francais')](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254119/package-babel-error-unknown-language-french-not-francais), I install the package `texlive-lang-french` with `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-french`, but the problem still exists. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: For a start it would be nice to give a link to the template. You are using `french` for some reason, and this seems to not be found on your system.

Comment: @Johannes_B, thx for pointing out this. I'll find it out and update my question.